# Bouncycastle fails in android API < 21

Tags: android, bouncycastle

i am trying to run some spongycastle code in android:

```
    try {
        Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("P-256");
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");
        generator.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        String publicKeyStr = publicKey.getW().getAffineX().toString() + ":" + publicKey.getW().getAffineY().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, publicKeyStr);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date d0 = c.getTime();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date expiry = c.getTime();
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuedAt(d0)
                .setSubject("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")
                .setExpiration(expiry)
                .signWith(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.ES256).compact();
        Log.d(TAG, token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

in API version 21+, it works as expected.

in API version 18, it works in debug.  in release, it fails in function `generator.generateKeyPair()` with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point`.

in API version 16, it fails in function `Jwts.builder().signWith()` with `io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: Invalid Elliptic Curve PrivateKey. can't recognise key type in ECDSA based signer`.

any idea what i am doing wrong?

**edit**:  i have apparently fixed the problem by switching from spongycastle to bouncycastle.

in my `build.gradle` i changed this:

```
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.60'
```

and in my code i got rid of this line:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

and added these lines:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

and i changed the provider from `"SC"` to `"BC"`.

and now my code works as i would like, for all versions of the android API.

my concern now is the comment at this link...

[Spongy Castle: is it obsolete?](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/34)

...by the author of spongycastle:

> **Why might Spongy Castle *not* be obsolete?**
>
> ...
>
> even on post-Android 3.0 devices, device manufacturers are not above
>   carelessly bundling libraries, it's possible that Bouncy Castle may
>   still be bundled on some obscure devices.

what does that mean exactly?  could it cause my code above to malfunction on certain devices?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters, but just to verify this which version of the spongycastle library are you using?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  i was running spongycastle version 1.58.  i have apparently fixed the problem by switching to bouncycastle 1.60.  is that a good solution?  i edited my OP with additional information.

Comment: Bouncycastle 1.60 (or 1.61 which is current now) should be fine. I wouldn't worry about rtley's concern about careless bundling, I think it is very unlikely and yours would not be the only app affected if that ever happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bouncy castle:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60"
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.60"
}
```